# Typescript React Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the below webpack.config.js file :

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./Scripts/src/index.tsx",
output: {
    filename: "./wwwroot/Scripts/dist/bundle.js",
},

// Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".scss",".css", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      {
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
      options: {
        sass: false,
        modules: true,
        camelCase: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        namedExport: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
      }
    },

  ]
},
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'file-loader?&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=images/[name].[ext]' },
    ],


}
}
```

I have the below tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./Scripts/",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"jsx": "react",
"lib": [ "es5", "es6", "dom" ]
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"wwwroot"
]
```

}

My Package.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "react-typescript-vs",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "React TypeScript VS 2017",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "webpack"
},
"keywords": [
  "abhilash",
  "react",
  "typescript",
  "vs2017"
],
"author": "Abhilash D K",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-scripts-ts": "2.8.0",
  "typed-css-modules-loader": "0.0.11",
  "typescript": "^2.6.2",
  "webpack": "^3.10.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^21.1.8",
  "@types/node": "^8.0.54",
  "@types/react": "^16.0.27",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
  "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
  "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
  "chalk": "1.1.3",
  "css-loader": "0.28.7",
  "dotenv": "4.0.0",
  "eslint": "4.10.0",
  "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
  "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
  "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
  "file-loader": "1.1.5",
  "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
  "jest": "20.0.4",
  "object-assign": "4.1.1",
  "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
  "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
  "promise": "8.0.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
  "radium": "^0.19.6",
  "raf": "3.4.0",
  "react": "^16.1.0",
  "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.1.0",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
  "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
  "style-loader": "0.19.0",
  "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
  "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
  "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
  "url-loader": "0.6.2",
  "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
  "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
}
}
```

I have a Scripts/src folder. Under which I have a components folder with Hello.tsx with below content :

```
import * as React from "react";
export interface IHelloProps {
    text: string;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<IHelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return(<div>{this.props.text}</div>);
    }
}
```

Under Scripts/src folder I have a index.tsx file with below content:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Hello text="Hello from React Typescript...." />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Everything works fine. Now I will add Hello.css file with .textColor { color: azure } as it's content and i don't even use it. When I run webpack and try to access index.html I get the below error :

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I tried adding module: commonjs as well as module : es6 to tsconfig.json. Still same error.

Could somebody explain me what is the problem and give me a solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `console.log` the `Hello` component to see what you are getting.

Comment: I am getting an empty object

Comment: I tried with export default too. But still got the same error. The problem was have the same filenames for both .tsx and .css files and the order of extensions in webpack.config file as specified by @dalinarkholin

Answer (score 3):

Could have something to do with the way you are trying to import Hello.

Try:

```
import * as Hello from './components/Hello';
```

Edit:

Sorry I just saw what is wrong here. What you are importing from hello is not a React Component, it is an object that holds all your classes. so in your case it would look something like:

```
{
  textColor: "referenceToActualClassName"
}
```

So you wouldn't use it as:

```
<Hello>
```

but instead as

```
<div className={Hello.textColor}></div>
```

Let me know if that fixes it.

ANOTHER EDIT:

No...you probably do have a component there. The problem is your component file and styles file are both named *Hello*.

```
extensions: [".scss",".css", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
```

Order matters here. So you are trying to import Hello from the css file. Be explicit with file extensions or rename the styles file to styles.css or theme.css or something.

Comment: Changed my answer. Try that instead.

Comment: Changed the way of importing Hello and also Updated <Hello /> to <Hello.Hello />. Still same error.

Comment: Another Update. Think I have it now.

Comment: Thanks. I renamed the Hello.css file to HelloStyles.cs file. The error is gone. Now I try to import the style in Hello.tsx file as "import * as s from './HelloStyles.css'" But again getting the error as "Property 'textColor' does not exist on type HelloStyles.css. Sorry I am new to React. Could you tell me how to import the style. When I just tried import './HelloStyles.css' and apply  className="textColor" no error but style is not applied. I also modified the ordering of extensions and kept .css and .scss at the end.

Comment: try:  import HelloStyles from './components/HelloStyles'; then <div className={HelloStyles.textColor}></div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160650/discussion-between-dalinarkholin-and-abhilash-d-k).

Comment: Hello.tsx and HelloStyless.css are under components directory. So i guess you meant ../components/HelloStyles.css. If yes I tried, the error says HelloStyles.css has no default export.